# Splitting string to words adds spaces to words array

Tags: javascript, split

So I'm splitting my string like this:

`string.split(/\W+/);` or `string.split(' ');` in both ways it does the good job, as we have string:

ex. **string = "this splits well";**
split result: **['this','splits','well']**

I need only words in this array, so job done, but if we add a space to begining or ending of string, that space will be taken to array, example:

**string = "this splits not well ";**
after **split = ['this', 'splits', 'not', 'well', ' ']**

How to avoid that space? Can I avoid id in during split, or should I remove them after split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the string before your call to split.

```
string.trim().split(/\W+/);
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used this trim function yet, seems to be very handy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var str = "this splits well";
var words = str.match(/\w+/g);
```

Instead of splitting your string, this method catches only the words.